# How to concatenate sql, html and php with this code

Tags: php, html, mysql, concatenation

Basically it is an element which shows an image from the path on database. But I just can't make it work.

```
<img class="img-circle profile_img" id="blah" src=" <?php $query2=mysqli_query($conexao,"select * FROM esc_usuarios_fotos WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
        if ((!empty($row2['img_local'])) && (file_exists($row2['img_local']))) {
            echo '<img class="image--cover" id="blah" src="'.$row2['img_local'].'" alt="Avatar" title="DEFINIDA" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=1.png;">';
        } else {
            echo 'Show a default image.'; // <img src="path_to_default_image" alt="Default_image"/>
        }
    } ?>" alt="Avatar" title="DEFINIDA" >
```

Comment: You are echoing out an entire img tag. Echo out only the Source (src/url) of the image. And replace 'show default image' with the location of a default placeholder file.

Comment: There are two things you need to look into before you put anything on line: 1 Prepared Statements, 2 escaping HTML on variables that will be used in HTML code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @Juan Prepared Statements, i'm stilll studying that, but what about escaping variables? I'm sorry, kinda new in English

Comment: Escaping variables before including them in html prevents that certain characters are interpreted as code, enabeling javascript injection. Look into this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work, the final code:

```
<?php
            $query2=mysqli_query($conexao,"select * FROM esc_usuarios_fotos WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");
            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
                if ((!empty($row2['img_local'])) && (file_exists($row2['img_local']))) {
                    echo '<img class="image--profile" src="'.$row2['img_local'].'" title="Clique para abrir seu perfil">';
                } else {
                    echo '<img class="image--profile" src="images/user.png">';
                }
              }
            ?>
```